# Convert Docker image to Google Compute Engine VM image

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Docker image (in Ubuntu 14.04 environment) that I want to upload to Google Compute Engine and run as a Compute Engine (not App Engine) instance.

There is a [presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1SbCiZwOLwgAii2WfhcD7jw0i63x9tUo4azzfxMlfiR4/edit#slide=id.g2aef54090_0862) (by Google's Marc Cohen) about how to do this but it leaves out key steps (on page 34) about how to convert the Docker image to raw `tar.gz` format.

Can someone tell me the exact steps to

- convert Docker image to correct format
- upload to google storage
- create google compute engine image
- start google compute engine instance

Comment: Note that you can run Docker images directly on GCE VM instances (without converting them to VM images) if you use [container-optimized Debian](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms) or [CoreOS](https://coreos.com/docs/running-coreos/cloud-providers/google-compute-engine/) images.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bound to your Ubuntu image, then you could just use the ready made VMs with Docker support (Debian Wheezy) and drop your containers in.

For more info on using Docker on GCE, see:

- [Container-optimized Google Compute Engine images](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms)
- [Containers on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation on packaging](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#buildingimage) has comprehensive steps to do all what you have enumerated.

There are some specific requirements that your install must include in order for it to be compatible with GCE; its a long list of kernel compatibility flags, disk types, NTP settings, etc. etc. so copy-pasting it here will not be prudent as this information is likely to change as GCE is updated by Google.

Comment: i want to convert an existing Docker image to disk.raw format. the instructions which you mentioned do not seem to explain how to do this.  they start with blank disk.raw.

Comment: You can try the dd Linux command to image your disk.  dd if=[device source] of=[image destination] bs=[size] where your [image destination] will be disk.raw and then you'll need to tar this file.